# AngularJS check if downloaded json has difference between working copy

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I download json so:

```
$scope.getarticles = function(company) {
  $http.get("url", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'If-Modified-Since': ''
      }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
      $.each(response, function(ind, el) {
        $scope.articles.push(el);
      });
    })
    .error(function(err, status) {
    });
};
```

and i work with my $scope.articles and there for some objects i could change data (note, that it could also have sort uid etc, do not compare them) - how to compare my data with data that i get from json? like

```
     $.each($scope.articles, function(ind, el) {
        if (el == $scope.copyArticles)
          console.log("yes");
      });
```

is it real somehow to do? if yes, then how?

Comment: `stringify($scope.articles.slice().sort(sortArticles)) === strinfigy(response.sort(sortArticles));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy built-in way, especially if you have to ignore certain fields, such as sort UID.

It just goes back to basic Javascript.

For instance, define a function to compare if two articles are equal, ignoring any fields you don't care about. For convenience, I am using the `_.omit()` function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) or [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) to remove the keys I don't care about, and using `angular.equals()` to do a deep comparison on the resulting object.

```
function articlesAreEqual(article1, article2) {
    return angular.equals(strippedArticle(article1), strippedArticle(article2));
}

function strippedArticle(a) {
    return _.omit(a, 'sortUID' /* add other keys here */);
}
```

Then you can see if any of the downloaded ones match the existing ones:

```
$scope.getarticles = function(company) {
  $http.get("url", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'If-Modified-Since': ''
      }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
      $.each(response, function(ind, el) {
        if (articlesAreEqual($scope.articles[ind], el)) {
            console.log('Article #' + (ind + 1) + ' is the same.');
        } else {
            console.log('Article #' + (ind + 1) + ' differs.');
            $scope.articles.splice(ind, 1, el); // replace the existing one
        }
      });
    })
    .error(function(err, status) {
    });
};
```